# Error when trying to import script in root directory

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── __init__.py
├── http
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── web.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── app.py
```

Inside the app.py file:

```
from http import web
```

When I try to run (in the root dir):

```
 python test/app.py
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: no module named http
```

I know that I could run using:

```
python -m test.app
```

However, there is another way?

Comment: Turn your entire project into a Python package, install it into a virtual environment, now you should be able to import things from your project from any working directory.  See https://packaging.python.org/ on how you should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `python path/to/script.py`, python adds the directory containing `script.py` to the module search path, but doesn't magically add anything else.  So when you run `python test/app.py`, and `app.py` tries to `import http`, it's not found because the `http` module isn't anywhere in the search path.  An easy way of solving this would be:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PWD python test/app.py
```

This would add your current directory to the module search path.  Assuming that you current directory is the one that contains the `http` module, this would allow `app.py` to sucessfully import `http`.